# JavaScript Using MutationObserver Multiple Times (DRY)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `function` that prints to the `console` the `attributes` changes of the passed `element` using `MutationObserver`. 
In the example below, I'm passing the `card`'s as an argument in `foreach loop`:

```
track_attr_changes(element);
```

parameter `current` in the `function`:

```
function track_attr_changes(current){
     ...
     ...
     observer.observe(current ,config);
}
```

And it `return mutation` in the `console`:

```
return console.log(mutation);
```

The point is to track all the `attr` changes for more than one `element`. So I can use it for multiple `element` and checking more than one specific `attribute`

**The Problem**: 
*How can I `return mutation` stored in a variable for checking conditions?* 
I want to change the `attributes` depending on few conditions, and each `set` of `cards` has its own `attributes` so I need the `mutation` for every passed element.

**What I've tried:**

- declaring `var y;` is the `loop` and passing it as an `argument` and `return y = mutation`. But it returns `undefined` since `MutationObserver` is nested `function`:

```
var y;
track_attr_changes(element, y);

function track_attr_changes(current, y){
     return y = mutation;
     observer.observe(current ,config);
}
```

**Code Example:**

```js
function track_attr_changes(current){
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            return console.log(mutation);
        });
    });
    var config = { 
        attributes: true,
        attributeOldValue: true,
        subtree: true
    };
    observer.observe(current ,config);
}


var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
cards.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        element.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    track_attr_changes(element);
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #999;
    margin: 35px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #555;
}

.card.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need one instance of MutationObserver and check your conditions in the callback

Simple example

```js
const targetNode = document.querySelector("#container");
var config = { 
    attributes: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    subtree: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(observerCallback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

function observerCallback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    const {type, attributeName, oldValue, target} = mutation;
    if(type === 'attributes' && attributeName === 'class' && target.matches('.wrapper .card')){
        const {className} = target;
        target.textContent = `Class changed from "${oldValue}" to "${className}"`;
        console.clear()
        console.log({oldValue, className })
    } 
  });
}
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
cards.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        element.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    
});

const wraps = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
wraps.forEach((el,i)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    el.querySelector('.card:nth-child(2)').classList.add('test_'+i)
  },500*(i+1))
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">Item #1</div>
    <div class="card">Item #2</div>
    <div class="card">Item #3</div>
    <div class="card">Item #4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">Item #5</div>
    <div class="card">Item #6</div>
    <div class="card">Item #7</div>
    <div class="card">Item #8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```